# SARSA implementation with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, sarsa

I try to learn the concept of reinforcement learning at the moment. Hereby, I tried to implement the SARSA algorithm for the cart pole example using tensorflow. I compared my algorithm to algorithms which use a linear approximation function for the q-value function and find my algorithm to be very similar. Unfortunately, my implementation seems to be false or inefficient as the learning success is rather limited. Is there anyone who can tell me if I am doing something wrong and what it is? The code of my implementation is:

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import random
import gym


#define a neural network which returns two action dependent q-values given a state
neural_net = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'relu', input_shape = [4]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])

#return the neural network's q-value for a specific action
def q_value(state, action):
    return neural_net(tf.convert_to_tensor([state]))[0, action]

#act either randomly or choose the action which maximizes the q-value
def policy(state, epsilon):
    values = neural_net(tf.convert_to_tensor([state]))
    if np.random.rand() < epsilon:
        return random.choice([0, 1])
    else:
        return np.argmax(values)

#intialize gym environment
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')

#hyperparameters
discount = 0.99
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
episodes = 1000
epsilon = 0.30

#collect reward for each episode
rewards = []
for episode in range(episodes):

    #start trajectory for episode
    state = env.reset()

    #record rewards during episode
    sum_returns = 0

    #decrease random action after the first 100 episodes
    if episode == 100:
        epsilon = 0.10

    #Q-learning
    while True:
        action = policy(state, epsilon)
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        next_action = policy(next_state, epsilon)
        sum_returns += 1

        if done:
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                tape.watch(neural_net.trainable_variables)
                q_hat = q_value(state, action)
                y = reward
                loss = tf.square(y - q_hat)

            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, neural_net.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, neural_net.trainable_variables))
            break
        else:
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                tape.watch(neural_net.trainable_variables)
                q_hat = q_value(state, action)
                y = reward + discount * q_value(next_state, next_action)
                loss = tf.square(y - q_hat)

            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, neural_net.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, neural_net.trainable_variables))
            state = next_state

    rewards.append(sum_returns)

#plot learning over time
plt.plot([episode for episode in range(episodes)], rewards)
plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at your code and it seems that the neural network has no way of knowing that the new estimate for the Q value `y` is related to the action `a` that was selected since you passed the same state regardless of the choice that is made afterwards.

My recommendation would be to concatenate the state twice - since you have two actions - and when you select the first action you only add the current state once to the first half to this intermediate representation, leaving the second half of the vector empty. You would do something similar when choosing the second action, but you'd leave the first half of the vector empty.

Check out this link on Coursera I found when I was implementing SARSA: https://www.coursera.org/lecture/prediction-control-function-approximation/episodic-sarsa-with-function-approximation-z9xQJ